# SELECT com varios parametros em PHP

Tags: php

Bom o que pretendia era fazer um select, com varios parametros sem ser só com 1.

```
$verifica = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login='$login'");
```

No caso do código acima só tenho 1 parametro que é se o login = $login, mas queria fazer para adicionar mais parametros, ou seja mais condições, como por exemplo idade = $idade. Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login='$login' AND idade = '$idade'" - se quiser adicionar mais apenas coloque o "AND", mas não é uma boa prática passar as variáveis diretamente dessa forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Usando OR ou AND

Caso você queira adicionar mais atributos para filtrar sua busca você pode usar o AND ou o OR.
No caso teremos:

```
// Para AND (Irá retornar apenas as tuplas que tem LOGIN E IDADE que você informou na query)

$verifica = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login='$login' AND idade = '$idade'");

// Para OR(Irá retornar as tuplas que tem LOGIN OU IDADE que você informou na query)

$verifica = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login='$login' OR idade = '$idade'");
```

## Alerta

Esse tipo de consulta não é segura pois abre espaço para o ataque *sql-injection*, dê uma olhada no material abaixo:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php